# Optimize pandas unstack().apply().stack()

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a large pandas DataFrame that has a multi index of
['Date','Int1','Int2'] and single column that is floating point number.
Currently I am applying some normalization by doing:

```
data.unstack().apply(some_matrix_math, axis=1).stack()

def some_matrix_math(matrix):
 #do some matrix math to normalize
 return matrix
```

I am applying the normalization across 'Date','Int1' then would like to put the data frame back to having and index of ['Date','Int1','Int2'].

The above code works but is very slow on large data sets. I am wondering if there is a faster way to do the same thing?

Comment: using `.apply` is inherently slow. Without more details about your actual data-frame, and the function you are applying, it is hard to say. My inutition is that the `unstack(). ... .stack()` is the least of your worries concerning performance, it's the `.apply`

Comment: It does seem to be the work being done in the function i have written. Not sure I can share the function. It is essentially doing some straight forward normalization of the data. It takes the mean and stddev then does some matrix math using those values to make sure any very high values are normalized.

Comment: Is there a way to parallelize apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my function I convert the initial vector to ndarray by doing:

```
def some_matrix_math(matrix):
 ndarray = matrix.values
 #do some matrix math to normalize
 return matrix
```

I then use numpy functions and vectors instead of pandas series and things run on the order of 100x faster.

Answer (score 0):

I might have this wrong, but if I correctly understand what you want to do, `groupby` might be more suitable to what you are trying to do. You can use something along the lines of `data.groupby(level=['Date', 'int1']).apply(some_matrix_math)`

Here is an example with data to demonstrate this. This example normalizes the values by the sum of rows which have same `Date` and `int1`:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), (1, 1, 2, 2), (11, 12, 13, 14)], names=['date', 'int1', 'int2']))
In[2]: df
Out[2]: 
                0
date int1 int2   
a    1    11    0
          12    1
b    2    13    2
          14    3
In[3]: df.groupby(level=['date', 'int1']).apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())
Out[3]: 
                  0
date int1 int2     
a    1    11    0.0
          12    1.0
b    2    13    0.4
          14    0.6
```

Performance wise, for smaller array, `groupby` appears slower, but for larger ones, you see speed gainz.

```
In[69]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(80000), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')*20000, [1, 2, 3, 4]*20000, np.arange(80000)], names=['date', 'int1', 'int2']))

In[70]: %timeit df.unstack().apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1).stack()
83.5 ms ± 8.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In[71]: %timeit df.groupby(level=['date', 'int1']).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
40.5 ms ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I tried this and it does work but it is slightly slower.

Comment: My test showed 2x speedup, but probably that depends on how many groups you have.